# Create View 1 Field From 2 Table

Tags: mysql

How i can create a view in mysql 1 field from 2 table.
Example

```
Table 1 (teacher) :
Name_field
Michael
Jodi
Rachel

Table 2 (student) :
Name_field
Perry
Viole
Hamston
```

How i can make a view, and result :

```
Name_field
Michael
Jodi
Rachel
Perry
Viole
Hamston
```

Comment: First create a query with the results you want using UNION and SELECT.  Then turn it into a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CREATE VIEW on UNION of the two tables.

```
create view someview as
select name_field from table1 union
select name_field from table2
```